# Why style.css raises 301 if other files works properly using express.static?

Tags: node.js, express

Currently I'm learning expressjs, I don't understand why when using `express.static()` there is some files that work properly and other than don't.
Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'))

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log("server listening on port 5000...")
});
```

All the files that i wanna access are in the same folder. But only `style.css` has 301 status, there is ass well a file in the Chrome development network window called `styles.css/` and has the status 404. How could I fix it?
Here is my html for what's worth

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="descarga.jpg">
  <div> AAAA</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The file structure is:

```
nodeTutorial 
nodeTutorial/app.js
nodeTutorial/public/image.png
            /public/styles.css
            /public/index.html
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could You present your Project folder and file structure ?

Comment: I've update the question and add the file structure @MarioG8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mirrored Your project with small improvements.

From Your `folder & file` structure and `index.html` exactly from this **line** below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

...it appears that `styles.css` should has status 301 OK (in my case 304 below in output screen). `style.css` it looks like this file does not exist ??!
Try to **hard refresh** your Chrome browser `Ctrl+F5` and this issue should disappear. `style.css` cannot appear there ! Good Luck ;-)
Serving static files in Express [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

**folder & file** structure :

[image]

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.static("./public"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Static Files Express</h1>
    </div>
    <img src="run_013.jpg" class="img" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

**Output** (*chrome network*) *Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

[image]

*Tested with: "express": "^4.17.3" node 16.13.0 Ubuntu 20.04*

Comment: It workeddd!!! I only had to hard refresh. I guess the issue came from memory chache or something that don't understand. Thanks a lot.  @MarioG8

Comment: @3n9ff You're welcome ! ;-) Glad I could help You!